# While loop counting java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program which asks you how many persons there are and asks for each invidual person how many objects they want. I'm using a while loop but I don't know how to make a total. It has to count the amounts you put in.

I've searched for it, but couldn't find out how to do it.

```
public class BakkenTeller {
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int quantity = 0;
        int total = 0;

        JFrame venster = new JFrame("Hoeveel mensen zijn er");

        int personen = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(venster, "Met hoeveel zijn jullie"));

        while (i < personen) {
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(venster, "Hoeveel pintjes zal persoon " + (i + 1) + " consumeren"));
            i++;

            total = quantity + quantity;
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }


}
```

Comment: Replace `total = quantity + quantity;` with `total += quantity;`

Comment: Or `total = total + quantity;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
total = quantity + quantity;
```

to

```
total += quantity;
```

otherwise total is reset each loop